# self.presentingViewController returns UITabBarController not the view controller pushing it with presentModalViewController

Tags: ios5, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `tab` based application. One of the `views` in it is pushing a `modal view controller`. If I call `self.presentingViewController` within a `modal view controller`, it returns `tab bar controller`, not the `view controller` which is pushing it.

What am I missing here? Is there a reliable way to return a `view controller` raising modal?

Thanks.

Comment: I thought the answer might be parentViewController, which I'm finding works in iOS 8, but not 7, at least in my use case.

Answer (score 13):

Is this an iPhone app? If so, that explains the confusion. On iPhone, the only presentation style is `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` - which amounts to saying that *on iPhone, the root view controller is always the presenting view controller*. Well, in a tab bar interface, the UITabBarController's view is the root view controller.

You'll notice that on iPhone the modal view doesn't replace your view controller's view; it replaces the *whole interface*, meaning that it replaces the tab bar controller's view. This is because the tab bar controller really *is* the presenting view controller.

I'm guessing that on iPhone you really should not be sending `presentViewController:` or `presentModalViewController:` to a view controller contained by a tab bar controller. You should be sending it to the tab bar controller. The message is therefore being routed to the tab bar controller for you.

So, nothing interesting is going to happen with the value of `presentingViewController` unless you're on an iPad. On an iPad, you *can* make the modal view replace the view controller's view. To do so, the modal view's `modalPresentationStyle` must be `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext`. And in that case, its `presentingViewController` *can* in fact be the view that "pushes the modal view controller".

Answer (score 3):

From Apple's documentation:

> The default implementation of this property walks up the view
>   hierarchy, starting from this view controller. The first view
>   controller it finds that received the
>   presentViewController:animated:completion: method, or that has its
>   definesPresentationContext property set to YES is returned as the
>   value of the property. It keeps walking up the hierarchy until it
>   finds a value to return or it gets to the root view controller.

So, even though the other view controller pushed it, that view controller's view is covered by the modal view. They walk up the hierarchy until it finds a view controller that doesn't have its view obscured, or has `definesPresentationContext` set to YES, or until it reaches the root view controller, which in your case was the Tab Bar Controller.

I would say that the presenting view controller needs to set `definesPresentationContext` to YES to answer your question on how to return that view controller that presented the modal one.

Comment: Thanks so much for the point in the right direction. However, `definesPresentationContext` does not make any difference. UITabBar is still responding, i assume because it receives `presentViewController:animated:completion:`. I had to resort to registering the view controller with app delegate and referencing it that way.