# presentingViewController getting always UITabBarController

Tags: ios, ios5

I just add TabBarController + NavigationController. Previous to this everything was ok but now when I call presentingViewController from a modal, I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController
>   tableViewListado]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Instead of receiving the expected object (ViewController) I'm getting "UITabBarController", should I get the presenting controller in some different way when using TabBar and Nav controllers?

Without the TabBar/Nav I was using this:

```
ViewController *parentView = (ViewController *)[self presentingViewController]; 

[parentView something];
```

**Edit:**

Just find out that if I do this it works, but dont think this is actually the best way to do it:

```
ViewController *parentView = (ViewController *)[(UINavigationController *)[((UITabBarController *)[self presentingViewController] ) selectedViewController] topViewController]  ;

[parentView something];
```

Comment: you need to add some code where you are calling presentingViewController.

Comment: check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437908/self-presentingviewcontroller-returns-uitabbarcontroller-not-the-view-controller

Comment: yes, thats my same problem but and I read before but dont really get how to correct the problem

Comment: seems like you got a ugly solution, but what i suggest to you is to check your navigation stack hierarchy, then it will give you a clear idea what you need to fetch.

Comment: the solution you got is not wrong, it works for your case considering the design you have on your viewcontrollers.

Answer (score 8):

copy of my answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905961/modal-view-controller-not-calling-presenting-view-controllers-dismissmodalviewc/26185639#26185639)

from [Programming iOS 6, by Matt Neuburg](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html):

> On the iPad, when the presented view controller’s modalPresentationStyle is UIModalPresentationCurrentContext, a decision has to be made as to what view controller should be the presented view controller’s presentingViewController. This will determine what view will be replaced by the presented view controller’s view. This decision involves another UIViewController property, definesPresentationContext (a BOOL). Starting with the view controller to which presentViewController:animated:completion: was sent, we walk up the chain of parent view controllers, looking for one whose definesPresentationContext property is YES. If we find one, that’s the one; it will be the presentingViewController, and its view will be replaced by the presented view controller’s view. If we don’t find one, things work as if the presented view controller’s modalPresentationStyle had been UIModalPresentationFullScreen.

TL;DR
1. set `definesPresentationContext` to true on the desired `presentingViewController`
2. set `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` on the desired `presentedViewController`